# recaptcha in Matrix

Tags: matrix, element, riot.js

i need one help , i have been trying to do registration process using recaptcha (i am using matrix public server which requires recaptcha

However whenever i send my recaptcha response to server

it does not get accepted , which secret_key does server use to validate token?

i am following https://matrix.org/docs/spec/client_server/r0.3.0#post-matrix-client-r0-register